# Costmap does not change on movement

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

I do have a problem with my local costmap.
As I move with my robot, the map (slam gmapping) changes but the overlying costmap remains unchanged!!!

The launch files for the costmap work, since they are retrieved from move_base costmap. The costmap created under /move_base does change corresponding to the map! But as soon as I instantiate a costmap in my code, it does not update the costmap ...

Here is my rqt_graph:

[image: image description]

Thanks for your contributions,

BR Daniel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119981/costmap-does-not-change-on-movement/) by [dneuhold](https://answers.ros.org/users/5295/dneuhold/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2014-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved ... have a look at this question:

http://answers.ros.org/question/120756/costmaps-observation-buffer-has-not-been-updated/

---

Originally posted by [dneuhold](https://answers.ros.org/users/5295/dneuhold/) with karma: 205 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0